# How to concatenate date in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have a question about concatenating a Date column (datetime) type in Excel 2010. For some reason, when concatenating Date, the values show as numbers. Below is my attempt to concatenate it.

Given two columns in Excel 2010

```
Date                        ID
2/22/2010 12:00:00 AM       1
6/27/2001 12:41:30 PM       2
3/11/2004  9:00:00 AM       3
```

Here, I am using the CONCATENATE function to concatenate two columns into a #temp table but the values in Date show as below

```
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('40231','1')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('37069.5288194444','2')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('38057.375','3')
```

Is there a way in Excel 2010 that I can use to concatenate exactly what I wanted which is like column Date above?

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate dates in excel itself or how to insert the date values with that format into a temp table? I don't see you're concatenating them with CONCATENATE, but inserting them in different fields through SQL.

Comment: @Jerry, Yes I am asking how to concatenate dates in Excel itself. Then dump the result into a temp table which will be used in SQL server.

Comment: Ok, use Barry houdini's formula then.

Answer (score 9):

Try using TEXT function to set the date format as required, e.g.

`="Some text "&TEXT(A2,"m/d/yyyy")`

where A2 contains a date

change the "m/d/yyyy" part as required, e.g. if you want the time too:

`="Some text "&TEXT(A2,"m/d/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")`

Comment: This works perfectly. My last question is how to add the ID column in the text function? Thanks.

Comment: @joe Just concatenate it :) `="Some text "&TEXT(A2,"m/d/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")&B2` (if the ID is in B2)

Comment: @Barry & Jerry. Yes, Got it. Works like a charm! Thanks very much, Gentlement.

Comment: Not sure why this is not accepted as an answer. It helped me with same problem.